# MongoDB: How to call a function defined in another JS file?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a function defined called `func1` in file file_a.js

I have another file `file_b.js`, in which I want to use the function `func1`.
Can I do this inside mongo environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amended answer thanks to AD7six
Mongodb console can take multiple input file loaded in order specified.

Or you can use the built in load function like this

```
➜  mongotest  cat test.js
load("test2.js");
print("test.js");
foo();
➜  mongotest  cat test2.js
var foo = function() {
  print("test2.js");
};

➜  mongotest  mongo test.js
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6
connecting to: test
test.js
test2.js
```

test.js is the file given to mongodb console, it loads test2.js(containing function foo) and calls foo

Comment: "Mongodb console can only take 1 input file as it's argument" for a long time, I thought that was the case too - but [it isn't](https://gist.github.com/4af3464aecd2eb0c8783). Load function is pretty handy though..

Answer (score 2):

If you are meaning via the cli (are you?), you can load multiple js files via the mongo shell

```
$ mongo --help
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6
usage: mongo [options] [db address] [file names (ending in .js)]
```

Note file name **s**

Therefore, you can just load both files, and the contents of file_a will be available to file_b:

```
mongo [args] dbname file_a.js file_b.js
```